Odoo16 SearchPanel DEFAULT STATE configuration
Are there any Odoo16 developers? Does anyone know if it is possible to set a default value for searchpannel?
This is how it is initially set when we visit this page:

Expected result, set the default value as I want:

I know we have domain filters, but they will hide the select options from the searchpannel. I would like to know (if possible) to set my values ​​so that they are selected every time.

I never tried something in that direction, but setting a normal "filter" won't hide the options in the panel. So introducing search filters and using them as default filter in context (search_default_my_filter: True) should work.

I tried it, it gives the same result as searchpanel IF searchpanel had the option I specified in search_default_my_filter selected, but it still just hides searchpanel options, in my case I just want it (searchpanel) to be selected by default.

Hmm, was worth a test.
